# A group containing a copy of $S_n$ for $n = 1,2,\cdots$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

Suppose that $G$ is a group containing a copy of $S_n$ for each $n$. Does it mean that $G$ contains a copy of $S_\Bbb{N}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily, consider the group $G$ of *finitary* permutations of $\mathbb{N}$, that is, those elements of $S_{\mathbb{N}}$ that fix all but a finite number of elements, that is,
$$
G = \{ g \in S_{\mathbb{N}} : \text{the set $\{ a \in \mathbb{N} : g(a) \ne a \}$ is finite}\}.
$$

Comment: oh my God. Thank you !!

Comment: @RobertM, you're welcome

Comment: Of course, that group IS the one that some people call $S_\mathbb{N},$ and a reasonable question is whether any group containing a copy of each $S_N$ has a copy of that group (it is pretty clear that it does).

Comment: @IgorRivin, good observation.

Comment: @IgorRivin If $G$ is the group of finitary permutations of $\mathbb N$, and if $(E_n:n\in\mathbb N)$ is a family of pairwise disjoint subsets of $\mathbb N$ with $|E_n|=n$, and if $H=\{g\in G:\forall n\in\mathbb N\  g(E_n)=E_n\}$, then (it seems to me) $H$ is a group containing a copy of $S_n$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$ but $H$ does not contain a copy of $G$ as a permutation group. Does it contain a copy of $G$ as an abstract group? And was the question about abstract groups or permutation groups?

Comment: The direct product $X$ of the $S_n$ for all $n >0$  certainly does not contain the group $G$ of finitary permutations. Any nontrivial subgroup of $X$ has nontrivial finite normal subgroups, but $G$ has none. (In fact $G$ has a simple subgroup of index $2$, the alternating group on ${\mathbb N}$.)

Comment: @DerekHolt Will the direct product of $\{S_{10^n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, I mean the direct product of all symmetric groups on $10^n$ symbols, be a different group than your $X$ above?

Comment: Yes, it's a different group - for example, it contains no normal subgroup isomorphic to $S_m$ for any $m \ne 10^n$, but each contains the other as a subgroup.